# Is there a way to prevent users from enlarging the browser display?

Tags: internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I built a [site](http://jrscreative.com/) for a client that is appears fine at normal display but appears to break apart if you change the font size to Larger or Largest in IE7/8.

Is there a way to prevent users from changing the view?

In Webkit there is this option:

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

Is there anything that would work in IE?

thanks.

Comment: you should ask if there's a way to design a view that looks OK even if the user change his font size.

Comment: Viewport size and font size are two completely different things. Also, `textarea{resize:none;}` is a third. What is this really about?

Comment: Disagreeing with the premise is not cause for downvotes.

Comment: ok folks. The horse if out of the barn. Let's focus on the possibility of a solution for the current request. Starting from scratch is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, why would you? Your site should be [as accessible as possible](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10/). What if I have poor eyesight and need to increase the font size to see your site?

Comment: While I agree with you in principle, this is a client request and I am simply looking to see if there is an option to do it.